# Riemann/Lebesgue integrability of a function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f_n:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function defined as:

$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}1\ \text{if}\ x=r_n\\0\ \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

where $r_n$ is an enumeration of rationals in $[0,1]$. Then, is the limit  function $f=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n$ Riemann integrable/Lebesgue integrable?

I think the function is Lebesgue integrable, as its absolute value is bounded, since 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1\ \text{if}\ x\in\mathbb{Q}\\0\ \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$.
The function is easily seen to be non-Riemann integrable because of nowhere continuity. Am I right? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: It's $1$ when $x\in\Bbb Q$. It is zero almost everywhere, but continuous nowhere.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown but the sequence of rationals converges to irrationals right, since the set of rationals is not complete?

Comment: When you say *easily seen*... you're applying a non-trivial Lebesgue theorem about integrability of Riemann functions.

Comment: @vidyarthi The sequence cannot converge as it enumerates all the rationals.

Comment: I guess you forgot to say $1\le i\le n$ in the definition of $f_n$.

Comment: @AlejandroNasifSalum thanks! edited it.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net yes, exactly. I meant that the conclusion is immediate. By the way, if it does not converge, then is the sequence not even pointwise convergent?

Comment: @vidyarthi Sorry, there may be something misleading. Are you sure of your $f_n$ definition? As written, each $f_n$ is always vanishing except at a single point, namely $x_i$. If so, $\int f_n=0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ and $f_n$ converges pointwise to the always vanishing function.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net but still the limit function would be not riemann integrable, right?

Comment: @vidyarthi Right. And the best argument is the one of Maksim answer below. No need to bring sophisticated Lebesgue Riemann theorem here.

Comment: @AlejandroNasifSalum you are yourself editing the question. The question is as I stated before. Please do not edit the question any further.

Comment: I edited the definition of $f$ according to my previous comment. This way, $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$ as you defined it. That is, each $f_n$ moves another rational point from $0$ to $1$ while leaving the previous ones at $1$. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @AlejandroNasifSalum this is what happens if you edit the question. You could have shown that the convergence is not as I pointed out.

Comment: Ok, with these definitions $f_n$ converges pointwise to the zero function, not to $f$. All $f_n$ functions are Riemann and Lebesgue integrable since they have only one discontinuity. This is not related at all to the $f$ you defined.

Comment: @AlejandroNasifSalum yes, exactly. That is what I expected. So I think you should delete your answer?

Comment: Of course, I had already deleted it. In any case, I don't understand if this is a question about the $f_n$ functions or the function you called $f$. The way it is stated is quite misleading since it suggest that you assumed that $f$ is the limit of the sequence, which is not the case. I suggest that you reformulate for the question not to be downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ is not Riemann integrable, that is true, but the reason is not of missing any continuity. It is just that the upper Darboux sum will always be 1 and the lower Darboux sum will always be zero given any partition of $ [0,1]$ and therefore the function is not Riemann integrable.

Comment: so do you, as @mathcounterexamples.net pointed out, mean the pointwise limit of the sequence is the zero function?